Doubts on Carters book on Lie algebra
I was reading Carter's book on Lie algebras of finite and affine type, I have the following doubts.
Let $L$ be a semi-simple Lie algebra and $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $L$. Let $H=N^- \oplus H \oplus N^+$ be a triangular decomposition of $L$. Then from PBW theorem it follows that we have a decomposition of $U(L)$ as a vector space $U(L)=U(H) \oplus (N^- U(L) + U(L)N^+)$.
So far it is OK, then he says the following, which I don't really understand.
Since $N^-$ and $N^+$ are $H$-stable, we have $ad H(z)=0$ for any $z \in Z(L)$ implies that any element in the center of $U(L)$ can be uniquely written as $$z=h_z+\sum_ix_ih_iy_i$$ for $h_z, h_i \in U(H)$, $x_i \in N^-U(N^-)$ and $y_i \in N^+U(N^+)$.
Why should $z$ have such a decomposition ? How does $ad H(z)=0$ give a decomposition of $z$ as claimed ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please tell me which page your doubt is?
